# Максимально возможное число и минимально возможное число

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как решить задачу, смысл которой, заключается в том, чтобы пользователь вводил одно целое число n, потом n цифр(без пробелов). Далее их этих цифр должно быть составлено максимально возможное число и минимально возможное число. Я написала код, но если в последовательности был 0, то в минимальном числе первая цифра 0, что не должно быть. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 
int main ()
{
   
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    
    char A[n];
    int buf;
 
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        cin>>A[i];
       
     
    }
    
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<n-i+1; j++) 
        {
            if (A[j-1] < A[j]) 
                {
                    buf = A[j-1];
                    A[j-1] = A[j];
                    A[j] = buf;
                }
        }       
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        cout << A[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<n-i+1; j++) 
        {
            if (A[j-1] > A[j]) 
                {
                    buf = A[j-1];
                    A[j-1] = A[j];
                    A[j] = buf;
                }
        }       
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        cout << A[i];
    }
 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если поменять 0 с первой ненулевой цифрой?...

Comment: @Harry
 Как? Я пыталась

Comment: Вот так: `000234` -> `200034`.

Comment: Я понимаю, как это в программе сделать? @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: Когда вы составили строку, сделайте ещё один шаг: отыщите самый первый "не ноль" и поменяйте его местами с первым символом строки. Это не сложно, вы уже написали сортировку.

Comment: В какой именно строке надо это сделать? @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: Вам как автору программы виднее. Не заставляйте меня думать, что программу писали не вы.

Comment: Только вот хамить не надо. Я вас вежливо вроде спросила. А вот что вы думаете о моей программе-ваше дело. Я в себе уверенна, а на других плевать. @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: А сортировку цифр учше делать подсчетом (линейная сложность)

Comment: @avp, с этой точки зрения сортировку вообще не нужно делать. Сосчитали цифры при вводе и напечатали их в нужном порядке.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, именно так, только каждую цифру нужно печатать столько раз, сколько ее вводили. А это и есть сортировка подсчетом

Answer (score 1):

Да все просто...

```
    /***    
        Добавьте следующие 8 строк в программу 
        перед выводом наименьшего числа.
     ***/
    if (A[0] == '0')
    {
        int i = 1;
        while(A[i] == '0') i++;
        buf = A[0];
        A[0] = A[i];
        A[i] = buf;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Проверку и обработку случая, когда все введенные цифры — нули, допишите сами...

Но как-то странно выглядит — написать сортировку, и не написать такой простой код?

Comment: *`"Но как-то странно выглядит"`* -- видимо это гугловое образование...